# Asp.net Mvc and Core , How it works SelectListItem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, selectlistitem

[image]
I have user edit problem in my Edit actions.. when it comes to departmentDropdownlist
When I click a user to edit let say he/she belongs to administration, I want then show
administration in dropdownlist and offcourse below that all departments in the same dropdownlist.
But right now when I click Edit It shows me all departments in Id order.. like I want to add a new user.
I have role dropdown list. tha's woking fine. If the user is Employee .. it shows me first Employee then the rest of Role list.. If the user is Admin , then it shows me Admin
then below that the rest of role list. But when it comes to department it shows me the first departmentname which DeptId = 1 and so on. I tried in both Asp.Net Mvc and Core.  Here is my EditUser and EditUserViewModel

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(string id)
{
    EditUserViewModel model = new EditUserViewModel();
    model.ApplicationRoles = roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = r.Name,
        Value = r.Id
    }).ToList();

    model.DepartmentNames = context.Departments.Select(s => new SelectListItem
    {

        Text = s.DeptName,
        Value = s.DeptId.ToString()
    }).ToList();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (user != null)
        {
            model.Name = user.Name;
            model.Email = user.Email;
            model.ApplicationRoleId = roleManager.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result.Single()).Id;
            model.DeptId = context.Departments.Single(r => r.DeptName == context.Sites.....??????); //How to do here
                                                                                                    // ViewBag.DeptId = new SelectList(context.Departments, "DeptId", "DeptName", model.DeptId); // Even like this , shows the first id departmentname

        }
    }
    return PartialView("_EditUser", model);
}
```

My EditUserViewModel

```
public class EditUserViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationRoleId { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> DepartmentNames { get; set; }

    public int DeptId { get; set; }   // I have DeptId too in my AspNetUser table
}
```

Comment: I don't get what you're asking....and the problem you're having.

Comment: @DavidLiang thank you for your response. I have added now a Picture and I hope it is litle more understable...;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `User` table has `DepartmentId`, I don't know why you don't assign `model.DeptId` to it.

So instead of

```
model.DeptId = context.Departments.Single(r => r.DeptName == context.Sites.....??????);
```

You can just assign the `DepartmentId` from the user table, i.e.,

```
model.DeptId = user.DepartmentId;
```

On Razor when you build the dropdown using `TagHelper`, it should select the correct dropdown option value based on the id.

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="DeptId" asp-items="DepartmentNames"></select>
```

Comment: , my goodness.. I don't know what I was thinking. Thank you very much !